# How to Pass Variable Between 2 Events : onMessageExternal And onClicked

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have this code in my `background.js` file :

```
var productId = '';

chrome.runtime.onMessageExternal.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    productId = request; << *** I want to use this variable below ***
});


chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {

    chrome.tabs.query({ active: true, lastFocusedWindow: true }, function (tabs) {

        chrome.tabs.executeScript(null, {file: "script.js"}); << *** the variable above is not readable inside this file ***

    });

});
```

how to pass `productId` variable so it can be used by `script.js` file. thank you.

UPDATE :

I tried to use global variable as suggested, but it's not readable from the file.

Comment: Declare the variable globally (at the very first line of the file, for example)? Or use chrome.storage.

Comment: @wOxxOm : it's not readable from inside the `script.js`, bro

Comment: @wOxxOm : check my update above. thank you.

Comment: If you're using an event page, it's unloaded after 5 seconds so variables won't stick. Use chrome.storage.

Comment: Great Idea, Bro!